# What kind of diode is this?

Tags: diodes, identification

What kind do I replace this with?

[image]

Comment: A broken one... Are you sure it's even a diode? What is the reference number?

Comment: Please supply better picture(s), closer in and different angles. What is printed on the ident. Do you have another board which is not broken? Why is there another board underneath?

Comment: Well, I was trying to fix a zoom H1 handy recorder because of a diode burst, and I think it says Gs or Cs on the diode.

Comment: I just need to know what kind of diode to get to replace it because I don't know how many different kinds there are. The size of it is 2x1.2 mm

Comment: Oh hey it's you again. I will measure the diode on my good Zoom H1 and get back to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a diode, but a tantalum capacitor. When powered up, there should be about 3.3 volts across it.

To build off of what I replied to one of your earlier posts, try removing the capacitor and powering the device up. Decoupling capacitors might not be required for it to function. Replace it with any moderate capacitance cap if it still doesn't work.

> It might be a failed component causing a short. I've noticed that switching regulators can make a squeaking noise when they are being overloaded, causing the switching frequency to drop to audible ranges, and becoming sound through piezoelectric effects of capacitors.

Here are images from my known good Zoom H1:
[image: Closeup of cap]
[image: Zoom H1 known good]

Comment: Thank you so much! So now I know why I was confused about why a diode would be there. :)

Comment: By any chance, you know what kind of electronic I could get it from? If not, do you think an SMD capacitor would work?

Comment: I think the exact value for this component is pretty flexible. Any larger capacitance SMD capacitor should do the trick. Try different ones if it doesn't work. Though I recommend just taking the broken cap off and try powering on without any component there, as it might not be critical for operation.

Comment: I tried powering it on without it and it didn't work because it probably has to do with the toggle on/off circuit. So I'm going to go with SMD and see if it works.

Comment: It *looks* as though C273 in your pic says 476 on it, which would suggest 47 uF. Which is a bit too large to replace with ceramic, and regular electrolytics may not fit.

Comment: @LoganS.Colon While that may be the (only?) visible damaged component on the board, *something* caused it to pop. It's likely that there are more damaged components than just that cap...

Comment: The reason why I think it popped was that maybe I put the battery in the wrong way and there was no reverse voltage protection. If it wasn't that I might need the schematic file to figure it out.

Comment: Do you measure about 3.3 volts across where the capacitor should be?

Comment: It measured exactly 3.3 volts. So does that mean that that is the only thing wrong with it?

Comment: I don't have any electronics that have tantalum capacitors, so I am going to try cramming this one in.                                                                                                                              
                                           
             https://capousd.instructure.com/files/5914907/download?download_frd=1&verifier=0yiwXXEbbBpKwOsQgk956sfdMngTdv60eLRKYwEf

Comment: @RonBeyer Sometimes tantalum caps just burn up for no apparent reason. Especially if they are not grossly overrated (voltage) and the circuit is not current-limited.

Comment: I think I can buy one from LCSC Electronics, but I don't know how many uF I need.